# minted not finding pygments.sty after --shell-escape set

Tags: packages, texstudio, minted, pygments

when I run `pygmentize -V` in my terminal I get

`Pygments version 2.3.1, (c) 2006-2017 by Georg Brandl.`

my Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Commands -> PdfLaTeX is set to

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`

The first error log I get when trying to compile is:
`` File `pygments.sty' not found. ``

I know there is tons of questions regarding this, but I have looked most of them up without any solution.

my imports are in following order

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
```

The message I get when trying to run is

`Error: Could not start the command: PdfLaTeX`

To be fair, I can't get the error messages to dissapear. Even after deleting everything the log and the error message persists when trying to compile. I might have broken something pretty severily.

### **Edit**

apparently the compiler is misconfigured or something. After deleting everything and attempting to build it says

`Error: Could not start the command: Compile & View`

Even after restoring default command `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`, making sure it is the default compiler `PdfLaTeX` and deleting all auxiliary files.

even though the whole file is

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    
\end{document}
```

it won't compile.

Comment: On Windows, you need to add to the path of your system `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts` after finding the exact path on your computer (the given path is an example)

Comment: @AndréC I don't use windows, but it would make sense. However I have broken something pretty severely and has made a new post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567645/cant-compile-after-deleting-content

Comment: It's the same principle, you have to find in which folder the `pygmentize ....` script is located and add it to the PATH.

Comment: @AndréC have you seen my other post? I doubt that is the issue when not even including packages that utilizes any python highlighting or code for that matter

Comment: After resolving your your issue with `pdflatex` in itself, you should be good to go. And even in Windows you would not need to setup `PATH` for `pygmentize` to work (I use windows and `pygments` with `pythontex`).