# Can't compile after reinstalling

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texstudio

I had some issues regarding some python code highlighting packages for the `minted` package. I ended up trying to revert all the changes since I could not make it work. Apparently I might have broken the compiler afaik, since I was stuck with the message
`Error: Could not start the command: Compile & View`

Even after restoring default command `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and making sure it is the default compiler `PdfLaTeX` and cleaning aux files - the error still persisted.

I ended up purging TeXstudio, texlive and tex-common and reinstalling them. Yet the error **still** persists.

even trying to compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}    
    \section{Some section}
    something
\part{title}
\end{document}
```

results in an error.

When compiling with TexStudio I get the following error:
Compile results in `Error: Could not start the command: PdfLaTeX`

out of sheer frustration i deleted both python and pip with no hopes with nothing as the expected result.

### Edit

It should be noted that through some comments I think we can narrow it down to being a TexStudio configuration, since it does compile as expected through the terminal.

```
~/LaTex/bachelor-template » latex -v                                                                                                                                               127 ↵ jonas@jonas-ThinkPad-L480
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Compile it on command line.

Comment: @AndréC Hi and thanks! It does not output a ``.pdf`` in the folder, however I think it might have created the ``.aux`` along with a ``.log``. It ends of the ``.log`` saying ``No pages of output.`` too. So I am not sure if it is even working as expected, nor does it make me able to utilize a editor. Which really isn't sustainable atleast for my workflow.

Comment: Try adding text in your document environment

Comment: I have, even included some sections and some paragraphs. Still no output

Comment: What about if you move `\end{document}` at the last line of the document ?

Comment: @D.LaRocque what a dumb mistake, yes that creates a pdf when compiling manually! However TexStudio still cannot compile the file. I guess we can narrow it down to being TexStudio configurations then?

Comment: What's the problem now ?

Comment: @D.LaRocque the same as it was from the beginning, properly not stated explicitly enough through the post. I have made an edit, I cannot compile it through my LaTex editor TexStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on TeX SE !

I think that your code is not giving any output because you're not adding content in `document`. When you start working on a document in LaTeX, you have two different parts in your file :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% Preamble
% This is where you add packages and you set your layout

\begin{document}

% Content
% This is what will show up in your PDF

\end{document}
```

Edit: Concerning TeXStudio, I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95086) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98132) can help you. If you need to know where is `pdflatex` in your computer, you can use the following command in Command Prompt (if you're using Windows) :

```
whereis pdflatex
```

Comment: I will give you an upvote, but I really need it to compile inside TexStudio, since it is my LaTex editor and I can't really work properly, since it cannot compile hence I cannot even view the document inside TexStudio

Comment: How about now @JonasGrønbek?

Comment: the error still persists, after formatting the document TexStudio still does not compile properly

Comment: Even by setting pdflatex path ?

Comment: After setting the path it could compile but not view, so I ended up restoring default settings. Apparently it worked. Thank you so much for your time. It is really appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to reinstall Python and Pip, they are not related to LaTeX problems afaik ;)